# Gatsby's Graphql say "Cannot query field "allMarkdownRemark" on type "Query"" and don't appear gatsby-transformer-remark

Tags: gatsby

I install gatsby plugin on gatsby template with check gatsby public(https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-transformer-remark/). But the query don't appear to localhost:8000/___graphql.

I build gatsby-site to use `gatsby new [name]`

And install markdown plugin by `npm install --save gatsby-transformer-remark`

And add below line to `gatsby-config.js`.

```
plugins: [
  `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
]
```

I access to `localhost:8000/___graphql`.
But query isn't exist. Graphiql say **"Cannot query field "allMarkdownRemark" on type "Query"."**

I do delete cookie, change browser, restart PC, rebuild site, try to install other plugins.
But don't fix.

Anyone has solution? Please help me!

Comment: Hi @ttaka, `gatsby-transformer-remark` needs `gatsby-source-filesystem` in order to work. Did you config the `gatsby-source-filesystem` to include the folder in which `.md` files are stored?

Comment: Thank your reaction and solution, @drek. You are right! I could find "allMarkdownRemark" query! Thank you!

Comment: It cannot vote to the comment...? :(