# In Gatsby config how can I isolate the metadata object to it's own file but still be able to use it in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, metadata, gatsby

Learning Gatsby I've referenced the docs and learned about the [siteMetadata object](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-config/#sitemetadata). Not being a fan of cluttering up a file I wanted to see if I could isolate the metadata into individual files and bring it in but I'm experiencing a GraphQL error.

### structure

In root I created a directory:

```js
/config
```

*menuLinks.js:*

```js
module.exports = [
  {
    name: `Home`,
    link: `/`,
    img: 'a.png',
  },
  {
    name: `Articles`,
    link: `/articles`,
    img: 'b.png',
  },
  {
    name: `About`,
    link: `/about`,
    img: 'c.png',
  },
  {
    name: `Events`,
    link: `/events`,
    img: 'e.png',
  },
]
```

*siteMetadata.js:*

```js
const menuLinks = require('./menuLinks')

module.exports = [
  {
    title: `Project`,
    titleTemplate: `%s · a starting point`,
    author: {
      name: `foo bar`,
      summary: `Enter the foo`,
    },
    description: `Just fooling around`,
    url: `https://something.io`,
    logo: `/logo.png`,
    twitter: `foobar`,
    menuLinks,
  },
]
```

bringing it into *gatsby-config.js*:

```js
const siteMetadata = require('./config/siteMetadata')

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata,
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-postcss`,
    `gatsby-plugin-css-customs`,
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/content/images/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `events`,
        path: `${__dirname}/content/events/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-yaml`,
      options: {
        typeName: `Event`, // a fixed string
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `articles`,
        path: `${__dirname}/content/articles/`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              // It's important to specify the maxWidth (in pixels) of
              // the content container as this plugin uses this as the
              // base for generating different widths of each image.
              maxWidth: 1080,
              quality: 100,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `Project`,
        short_name: `Project`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#ffffff`,
        theme_color: `#ffffff`,
        // Enables "Add to Homescreen" prompt and disables browser UI (including back button)
        // see https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/#display
        display: `standalone`,
        icon: `static/icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
  ],
}
```

### error

```
 28:11  error  Cannot query field "menuLinks" on type "SiteSiteMetadata"  graphql/template-strings
```

and

```
76:9  error  Cannot query field "titleTemplate" on type "SiteSiteMetadata"  graphql/template-strings
```

### research

- [Using an Object in Gatsby Config File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56172958/using-an-object-in-gatsby-config-file)
- [Not able to add favicon in gatsby config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58786033/not-able-to-add-favicon-in-gatsby-config-file)
- [Gatsby's Graphql say “Cannot query field ”allMarkdownRemark“ on type ”Query“” and don't appear gatsby-transformer-remark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56070498/gatsbys-graphql-say-cannot-query-field-allmarkdownremark-on-type-query-an)
- [Cannot query field “x” on type “y”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64455525/cannot-query-field-x-on-type-y)

### question

I've cleaned the .cache and public directories with `npm run clean`. In *gatsby-config.js* how I can I isolate the metadata object into it's own files and also be able to reference it in GraphQL?

---

## Edit

After [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65955955/1952287) suggesting implementation of the spread operator:

### error

> src/components/seo.js   76:9  error  Cannot query field
> "titleTemplate" on type "SiteSiteMetadata"  graphql/template-strings

### code

./config/siteMetadata.js:

```js
const links = require('./menuLinks')

module.exports = [
  {
    title: `Project`,
    titleTemplate: `%s · a starting point`,
    author: {
      name: `foo bar`,
      summary: `Enter the foo`,
    },
    description: `Just fooling around`,
    url: `https://something.io`,
    logo: `/logo.png`,
    twitter: `foobar`,
    menuLinks: {
      ...links,
    },
  },
]
```

./config/menuLinks.js:

```js
module.exports = [
  {
    name: `Home`,
    link: `/`,
    img: 'a.png',
  },
  {
    name: `Articles`,
    link: `/articles`,
    img: 'b.png',
  },
  {
    name: `About`,
    link: `/about`,
    img: 'c.png',
  },
  {
    name: `Events`,
    link: `/events`,
    img: 'e.png',
  },
]
```

gatsby-config.js

```js
const metadata = require('./config/siteMetadata')

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    ...metadata,
  },
  plugins: [`gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`],
}
```

graphQL from seo.js:

```
const query = graphql`
  query SEO {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        defaultTitle: title
        titleTemplate
        defaultDescription: description
        siteUrl: url
        defaultImage: logo
        twitterUsername: twitter
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have better approaches to using menu navigation rather than putting them in the `siteMetadata` object like using `useStaticQuery` hook to make the navigation reusable. However, if you want to merge two objects you can easily do something like:

```
// gatsby-config.js
const siteMetadata = require('./config/siteMetadata')
const menuLinks = require('./menuLinks')


module.exports = {
  mergedObject,
  plugins: [
    ...
  ],
}
```

Or directly:

```
// gatsby-config.js
const siteMetadata = require('./config/siteMetadata')
const menuLinks = require('./menuLinks')

const mergedObject={...siteMetadata, ...menuLinks}

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata{
   ...siteMetadata,
   ...menuLinks
  },
  plugins: [
    ...
  ],
}
```

Comment: for some reason even if I implement this approach GraphQL still harps on `siteMetadata`. I'll make an edit.